# Why don't we use deleted functions?

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm reading Scott Meyers's [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) about copying objects, and came across the section about preventing copying the objects. Meyers suggest we declare a private constructor, and deliberately don't implement it. Like the following:

```
struct NotToCopy
{
void friend foo();
private:
    NotToCopy(NotToCopy&);
};
```

Now if someone try to copy the object of the type `NotToCopy` from the friend function they'll get a linker error. The question is why didn't we just use deleted function?

Comment: Probably because that book was written before the "deleted function" feature existed in C++. You may wish to acquire a copy of "Effective Modern C++" from the same author, which talks about this very question in Item 11 (page 74).

Comment: And in fact, I suspect the book at the top of the list you linked, *Modern* Effective C++,  probably does exactly what you're wondering about (I don't own it, so can't say for sure), but the 2014 date suggests it is likely).

Comment: BTW, it seems like a *compiler* not *linker* error.

Comment: @AmiTavory: it's a compiler error if the copy constructor is invoked outside of `NotToCopy` (or it's friends, like `foo()`), because the copy constructor is private. But if a member function or a friend function tries to create a copy, [it's a linker error](http://ideone.com/r9Nui3).